# get element Tag value from the xml

Tags: javascript, xml

this is my JavaScript code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation API with Google Maps API</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="getlg()">
    <script>
       function getlg(){
                var region = $('#region').val();
                var xml;
                $.ajax({
              url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+$("#region").html()+"&sensor=true",
              async: false,
              dataType:'text/xml',
              success: function(data){
                xml=data;
                $('#Div_Get').html('');
          }
          });
                        xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$xml = $( xmlDoc );
   var abc= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat")[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
          }
    </script>
    <div id="region">Rajkot</div>
    <div id = "Div_Get"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here i am try to set value in url and get the xml file.
now i try to get from this xml lat and long value.
i am try `getElementsByTagName` but not success nothing is output and give me error `xmlDoc is null` on this line `var abc= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat")[1].firstChild.nodeValue;`
please help me out of this.

thanks.

Comment: have you considered jQuery.parseXML(data)?

Answer (score 0):

Change you `datatype` from

```
dataType:'text/xml',
```

To

```
dataType:'xml',
```

And Please have a look at documentation for [Specifying the Data Type for AJAX Requests](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests).

Comment: when i try this `success: function(data){
    xml=data;
    var filename = $(xml).find('lat').text();
   document.write (filename); `its return me all latitude but i want only first.